# Optimization with and without exceptions after compilation - would the results be the same?

Tags: exception, optimization, compiler-construction, compilation, programming-languages

1. Given a program , that uses exceptions for its functionality : if we'd run the program with optimization at one time , and after that we'd run it without optimization - would the outputs of the both executions be the same ?
2. Given the same program , that doesn't use exceptions for its functionality - if we'd run the program with optimization at one time , and after that we'd run it without optimization - would the outputs of the both executions be the same ?

Both questions are taken from an interview that took place a few days ago ...

I think that the answer for the first questions is NO - since when some code line throws an exception , the scope is dynamic , and optimization would probably change the order of the execution of the program .Hence ,the outputs of two different executions (one with optimization and one without) might be different ...

Is this correct ?

What about the `2nd` question ?

Much appreciated :)

Comment: I'd have to ask them questions back, seeing as they are foolishly assumimng I either know or don't know they answer that they want. Whereas I'm actually struggling with the extreme pointlessness of the question unless, it was a for job writing compilers?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: student's position in programming ... you can assume that it also involves writing compilers .

Comment: Not a big fan of assumptions. :(

Answer (score 2):

Optimization is not supposed to change observable behavior. In general, the answer to both questions is yes. You don't mention language. For C++, there are a lot of situations where behavior is undefined, if that's the case you might see differences.

You write:

> optimization would probably change the order of the execution of the program .

While that's true, to an extent, C++ has the concept of a checkpoint that limits re-ordering.